# How to require a user to put a value on the textbox?

Tags: html, asp.net, vb.net

My problem is I have a textbox which needs user input only if the preceded question is answered by yes. I'm using already custom validator but this is only triggered when the user input something so this is only used for checking if the value is valid or not. I'm not sure about the requiredfieldvalidator because this will really require the user to input something even if he/she answer the preceded question as NO. Perhaps someone has a better idea, how will I require my user to input something on the textbox if he/she answered the preceded question with Yes.

[image]

Comment: You will have to create a CustomValidator.

Comment: @VDWWD  Custom Validator is not triggered unless you put something on the textbox, what if the user forgot to put something, the custom validator will not be triggered.

Comment: Yes it will, because a custom validator will trigger on form post.

Comment: Is there something I need to enable as attribute of Custom Validator? I used the Custom Validator, if I don't touch the textbox at all, the validator won't be triggered as I'm trying to debug it.

Comment: a validation ouccurs after you entered a character into the text vox

Comment: you need to think backswords if no is selected and a user tries to enter something you, don't allow it, you also could ignore it when you try to save it

Comment: The key phrase to search for is "dependent validation", https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2009776/asp-net-mvc-validation-dependent-fields

Comment: @nbk, if no is answered, the question 2a won't be displayed.

Answer (score 0):

I figured it out already, I need the attribute ValidateEmptyText = true so the custom validator will be triggered when the textbox is empty.